# How to customize WordPress' gravity forms

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

How do I customize the form before rendering it? Basically what I want to do is to change the label, add default values on input box, pre-populate and pre-select drop down. I've added a hook to handle the pre render event, unfortunately it didn't work.

The code below is for label customization only. What I expect to happen with this code is that the input box label should become "Test Label" after rendering the form.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
/* I've placed this code in template/function.php */

/*gravity forms*/
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render', 'customize_form' );

function customize_form( $form ) {

if($form['id'] != 6) return $form;

foreach ( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
    if ( $field['id'] == 10 ) {            
            var_dump($field['inputs']);
            $field['inputs'][0]['label'] = "Test Label";
    }
}

return $form;
}
```

Comment: To clarify, you're trying to change the field label of a "Drop Down" field in Gravity Forms, correct?

Comment: Hi @David I've already sorted this out. I used javascript  and this gravity form php code `gravity_form(3, false, false, false,  array('email'=>$_POST['subs_email']),  true)`  to pre-load and change the forms' value. Thanks anyway :)